# Why is ArrayList implementing List

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I was observing that `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` and implements `List`.
Now `AbstractList` itself implements `List`. Given that, what was the need to `ArrayList` to implement `List` at all ?

Comment: Interface is different from inheritance. An interface can be extended by another interface not by an class. It is not part of an class hierarchy.